# Getting null pointer Exception in Weblogic 14 when access to a specific jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, weblogic

Im having this error when I try access to a view, the strange is that this occurs on just 3 jsp views. The web app works perfectly on other views.
Im using Spring framework 5 and weblogic 14. This is the full stack trace.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.getHeader(ServletResponseImpl.java:1222)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:249)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:249)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.CacheControlHeadersWriter.hasHeader(CacheControlHeadersWriter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.CacheControlHeadersWriter.writeHeaders(CacheControlHeadersWriter.java:60)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.writeHeaders(HeaderWriterFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse.writeHeaders(HeaderWriterFilter.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse.onResponseCommitted(HeaderWriterFilter.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.doOnResponseCommitted(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:251)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.checkContentLength(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:241)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.access$200(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:637)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WLOutputStreamWriter.writeBytes(WLOutputStreamWriter.java:204)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WLOutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(WLOutputStreamWriter.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WLOutputStreamWriter.write(WLOutputStreamWriter.java:164)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WLOutputStreamWriter.write(WLOutputStreamWriter.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.DelegateChunkWriter.print(DelegateChunkWriter.java:119)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.print(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:190)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.print(JspWriterImpl.java:178)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:274)
at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._paginas._comunes.__piepagina._jspService(__piepagina.java:234)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:649)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:518)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:161)
at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._view._xml.__formulario._jspService(__formulario.java:148)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:649)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:290)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3866)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3829)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:40012)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2502)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2351)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2304)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1779)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1733)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

Answer (score 0):

It is a knwon bug in WebLogic Server 14c. You need to download and apply patch "Patch 32133880: JSP SERVLET RESPONSE IMPL GET HEADER THROWING NULL POINTER EXCEPTION"

Comment: Where can I download this patch, now it's happen on other part of the app. I realized that this happens when I connect other jsp using <c:jsp> but when I write the code directly it works

Comment: Patches are available at Oracle Support site (MOS) support.oracle.com
As an Oracle customer you may have access to this site

Comment: I dont have an account for Oracle Support. Is there any alternative in order to get these files?

Comment: i'm afraid not. If you have a valid licence you should have access to Oracle Support.